# How can I find the maximum number of cities that I can visit given a travel budget (in minutes) using a travel time matrix

Tags: python, traveling-salesman

I have a list of 12 cities connected to each other without exception. The only thing of concern is travel time. The name of each city is [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/datasets/cities/uk12_name.txt).  The distance matrix (representing travel time in minutes) between city pairs is [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/datasets/cities/uk12_dist.txt).

How can I find out how many cities I can visited given a certain travel budget (say 800 minutes) from a city of origin (it can be any of the 12).

You can't visit the same city twice during the trip and you don't need to worry about returning to your origin. I can't go above my travel budget.

Comment: There is no magical path other than brute force trying them all.  You'll need to use recursion.

Comment: Stackoverflow is to help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering


def find_cities(dist, budget):     # dist: a 12x12 matrix of travel time in minutes between city pairs; budget: max travel time allowed for the trip (in mins)

    assert len(dist) == 12        # there are 12 cities to visit and each one has a pairwise cost with all other 11 citis 

    clusters = []                 # list of cluster labels from 1..n where n is no of cities to be visited  

    dists = [0] + [row[1:] for row in dist]       # start-to-start costs have been excluded from the distances array which only contains intercity distances     
    linkage = 'complete'             # complete linkage used here because we want an optimal solution i.e., finding minimum number of clusters required  

    ac = AgglomerativeClustering(affinity='precomputed', linkage=linkage, compute_full_tree=True)          # affinity must be precomputed or function otherwise it will use euclidean distance by default !!! 
                        # compute full tree ensures that I get all possible clustesr even if they don't make up entire population! This is needed so that I can determine how many clusters need to be created given my budget constraints below  

    Z = ac.fit_predict(dists).tolist()   # AgglomerativeClustering.fit_predict returns list of cluster labels for each city 

    while budget >= min(dists):          # while my budget is greater than the minimum intercity travel cost, i.e., I can still visit another city
        if len(set(Z)) > 1:              # at least 2 clusters are needed to form a valid tour so continue only when there are more than one cluster left in Z
            c1 = np.argmax([sum([i==j for j in Z]) for i in set(Z)])      # find which clustes has max no of cities associated with it and that will be the next destination (cities within this cluster have same label as their parent cluster!)          # numpy argmax returns index of maximum value along an axis; here we want to know which group has most elements! 
            c2 = [j for j,val in enumerate(Z) if val == Z[c1]][0]         # retrieve first element from the group whose parent is 'cluster' returned by previous line      

            clusters += [c2 + 1]                             ## add new destination found into our trip plan/list "clusters" after converting its city id back into integer starting from 1 instead of 0 like array indices do!!              
            dists += [dist[c1][c2]]                           ## update total distance travelled so far based on newly added destination ... note: distances between two adjacent cities always equals zero because they fall under same cluster
            budget -= dists[-1]                               ## update travel budget by subtracting the cost of newly added destination from our total budget 

        else: break   # when there is only one city left in Z, then stop! it's either a single city or two cities are connected which means cost between them will always be zero!              

    return clusters   # this is a list of integers where each integer represents the id of city that needs to be visited next! 
    
def main():

    with open('uk12_dist.txt','r') as f:      ## read travel time matrix between cities from file           ## note: 'with' keyword ensures file will be closed automatically after reading or writing operation done within its block!!! 
        dist = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in f]       ## convert text data into array/list of lists using list comprehension; also ensure all data are converted into int before use!        

    with open('uk12_name.txt','r') as f:      ## read names of 12 cities from file              ## note: 'with' keyword ensures file will be closed automatically after reading or writing operation done within its block!!! 
        name = [line[:-1].lower().replace(" ","") for line in f]          ## remove newline character and any leading/trailing spaces, then convert all characters to lowercase; also make sure there's no space between first and last name (which results in empty string!) otherwise won't match later when searching distances!!

    budget = 800                             # max travel budget allowed (in mins) i.e., 8 hrs travelling at 60 mins per km which means I can cover about 800 kms on a full tank!                   

    print(find_cities(dist,budget), "\n")     ## print(out list of city ids to visit next!
    print("Total distance travelled: ", sum(dist[i][j] for i, j in enumerate([0]+find_cities(dist,budget))), "\n" )     # calculate total cost/distance travelled so far by adding up all distances between cities visited so far - note index '0' has been added at start because 0-2 is same as 2-0 and it's not included in find_cities() output above !

    while True:
        try:                                ## this ensures that correct input from user will be obtained only when required!!              
            budget = int(raw_input("\nEnter your travel budget (in minutes): "))   # get new travel budget from user and convert into integer before use!!! 
            
            if budget <= 800: break          ## stop asking for valid input only when the value entered by user isn't greater than 800 mins or 8 hrs !!                              

        except ValueError:                   ## catch exception raised due to invalid data type; continue asking until a valid number is given by user!!                     
            pass

    print(name[find_cities(dist,budget)[1]],"->",name[find_cities(dist,budget)[2]],"-> ...",name[find_cities(dist,budget)[-1]] )## print out the city names of cities to visit next!

    return None

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: I am getting a ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0 list([300, 352, 466, 217, 238, 431, 336, 451, 47, 415, 515])
 list([0, 638, 180, 595, 190, 138, 271, 229, 236, 214, 393]) - also can I add an origin city name?

Comment: Standby. Examining code and will get back to you shortly. Email me if you have a moment. I have a question for you that will elicit a conversation. 
(up-for-reviews at pm.me)